# C# - Can't update my PostgreSQL with data adapter

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have one button to DELETE row from DataGridView.

Have another button to UPDATE. When i press it, nothing happens and i get some kind of error leading to data adapter but there is no explanation what is wrong.

If i enter data for new row and press UPDATE , same happens.

Here is the main code:

```
// Pievienojam 'darbinieks' DataTable + SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE
dt_darbinieks.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id_darbinieks", typeof(int)));
dt_darbinieks.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("darb_vards", typeof(string)));
dt_darbinieks.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("darb_uzvards", typeof(string)));
dt_darbinieks.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("pers_kods", typeof(string)));
dt_darbinieks.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id_amats", typeof(int)));

adapter_darbinieks.SelectCommand = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM darbinieks", ncon);

adapter_darbinieks.InsertCommand = new NpgsqlCommand("INSERT INTO darbinieks(darb_vards,darb_uzvards,pers_kods,id_amats) VALUES (@darbs_vards,@darbs_uzvards,@pers_kods,@id_amats)", ncon);
adapter_darbinieks.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@darb_vards", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 255, "darb_vards"));
adapter_darbinieks.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@darb_uzvards", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 255, "darb_uzvards"));
adapter_darbinieks.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@pers_kods", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 255, "pers_kods"));
adapter_darbinieks.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@id_amats", NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "id_amats"));
adapter_darbinieks.UpdateCommand = new NpgsqlCommand("UPDATE darbinieks SET darb_vards = @darb_vards, darb_uzvards = @darb_uzvards, pers_kods = @pers_kods, id_amats = @id_amats WHERE id_darbinieks = @id_darbinieks", ncon);
adapter_darbinieks.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@darb_vards", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 255, "darb_vards"));
adapter_darbinieks.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@darb_uzvards", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 255, "darb_uzvards"));
adapter_darbinieks.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@pers_kods", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 255, "pers_kods"));
adapter_darbinieks.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@id_amats", NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "id_amats"));
adapter_darbinieks.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@id_darbinieks", NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "id_darbinieks"));    
adapter_darbinieks.DeleteCommand = new NpgsqlCommand("DELETE FROM darbinieks WHERE id_darbinieks = @id_darbinieks", ncon);
adapter_darbinieks.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@id_darbineks", NpgsqlDbType.Integer, sizeof(int), "id_darbinieks"));
adapter_darbinieks.Fill(dt_darbinieks);
DGV_darbinieks.DataSource = dt_darbinieks;
ds.Tables.Add(dt_darbinieks); // Pievienojam DataSetam klāt DataTable
```

Here is the code for DELETING ROW:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in DGV_darbinieks.SelectedRows)
{
    DGV_darbinieks.Rows.RemoveAt(item.Index);
}
```

And the code to UPDATE DataTable and PostgreSQL:

```
adapter_darbinieks.Update(dt_darbinieks);
dt_darbinieks.Clear();
adapter_darbinieks.Fill(dt_darbinieks);
```

**Error (as supplied by OP in comments)**

> adapter_darbinieks.Update(dt_darbinieks); With the error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.dll Additional information: Backend sent unrecognized response type: i

Comment: What exactly is "some kind of error"? This is probably the thing we need to know to solve your problem. The second piece of information would be: which line of code causes that error message.

Comment: Post the error message as well.

Comment: Pointing me to this line: adapter_darbinieks.Update(dt_darbinieks); With the error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Backend sent unrecognized response type: i